# Using past in gpt2

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to run a script example from the huggingface documentation:

```
import torch

tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2')

generated = tokenizer.encode("The Manhattan bridge")
context = torch.tensor([generated])
past = None

for i in range(100):
    print(i)
    output, past = model(context, past=past)
    token = torch.argmax(output[..., -1, :])

    generated += [token.tolist()]
    context = token.unsqueeze(0)

sequence = tokenizer.decode(generated)

print(sequence)
```

But I have an error:

```
TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'past'
```

What should I change to use 'past'?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating `past` to `past_key_values`. I believe the documentation has been changed.

Comment: Thank you, it really helped!